# Monitoring a periodic task in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am using eFax to send faxes from my Rails 3.1 app and am wondering what the best way to monitor the status of each fax is.  EFax allows you to post a request with an id to find its status and I would like to do this every minute until the fax status is either successful or failed. I am considering creating cron jobs for each fax and then canceling the cron job after success or failure.  Or a better solution may be some sort of periodic job server?  Does anyone have any experience with something like this or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to create a rake task in your application that finds the fax tasks you need to check and then updates them.  Stick it in a cron job and your good to do.  Check out [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for configuring the cron jobs for you.

I would like to suggest a nice job scheduling system but I have been looking for on to use in Rails for several years.

Answer (score 1):

Use Delayed Job. http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job
It will retry N times for you on errors, you can schedule priority or future times to run. You could do a rake task in a crontab as well but it could possibly take a long time to startup every minute, consuming resources.

If you really need it to run on the minute exactly, consider cron with the whenever gem, http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby